# In .Net Core, how do I display different pages based on Exception type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Recently started using .Net 6.0 in a new project after only having experience in Framework 4.8. In my old projects, I was able to set up a redirect based on the exception type so that certain errors could display differently. I did this through overwriting the Application_Error and InvokeErrorAction methods. I was wondering if something similar could be achieved in 6?

Comment: You would typically add exception middleware that can handle your responses: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

from what you're describing, it seems like you are looking to implement try-catch blocks with specific exception handling conditions. If you wanted to make it so a specific exception causes as specific redirect to occur, I suppose you could have the .NET code try an action, if that action fails, catch the exception, and if you know a specific exception type should be occuring, you then catch that specific exception, and have a redirect occur. If  it's an unplanned exception, still have a generic catch block that let's you know the exception + redirects as appropriate. Here is a *very* generic example:

```
try{
    //A block of code to attempt
}catch ([Application_Error you were overwritting before] e) {
    //Alternative block of code + redirect you want in this instance
}catch (Exception e){ //This will be a generic catch-all for remaining excpetions
    //Last block of code + probably want to print the exception + redirect you want
}
```

If you do need this to be more generic to scale across other forms, I would then look at using a "exception handler class" you build yourself and have brought into any given form that needs this process, where you then create a single try-catch in the form you are working in, and its generic catch sends the exception to your error handler's "handle_exception" function, which then does the code blocks from the above example, but has it in a switch statement based on the exception, rather than try-catch.

This all is probably more convuluted than what you were looking for, and there maybe a configuration you could do to .NET Core to override certain errors, but  I have not tried that before and would veer away from doing a universal override of an error into a different action. I would do this more situation system instead that lets me handle the exception differently based on the circumstances.

The documentation for other elements of .NET try-catch is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch